# How do I stop the construction of a hidden pirate base on one of my planets?

Tags: distant-worlds-shadows

After establishing a new colony it was quickly raided by a pirate faction. I've since deployed a fleet in patrol around the planet and garrisoned some troops on it.

However, I can now see a hidden pirate base being constructed in the planetary facility section.

[image]

No clue what the successful completion of this base will mean for the planet but I'm guessing it won't be good. How can I stop the completion of this base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Colonies Manager (the <kbd>F2</kbd>). Select the colony in question, go to the `Facilities` tab (far right on the bottom) and select the Hidden Pirate Base. The `Scrap` button should change to `Attack`.

[image: Selected HPB]

When you select attack, any troops you have on planet will engage in a normal land battle. If you win, the base will be removed.

[image: Attack underway]

For reference, the base in the screenshots is 19% complete. I'm not certain if the completion level effects how difficult it is to remove.